# how to bind the following to the local this context variable on button click event?

Tags: javascript

I seriously need help on this.
How do I print the lat and long using a button click event like:

```
<button id="geo" onclick="OnGeoClick()"> Get Location </button>
```

I have the following code:

```
var getGeo = {
    showPosition  : 
    function showPosition(position) {
        self = this;
        console.log(self)
        self.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        self.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        console.log(self);
    },


    showError :
    function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                this.err = "User denied the request for Geolocation.";
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                this.err = "Location information is unavailable.";
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                this.err = "The request to get user location timed out.";
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
              this.err = "An unknown error occurred.";
              break;
        }
    },

    getLocation :
    function getLocation() {
            self = this;
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(self.showPosition, self.showError, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
                console.log(self);
            } else { 
                self.err = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }
};

function OnGeoClick() {...local this context binding?...}
```

such that window does not store lat and long but an accessible variable that can log(result) out;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bind method to keep the context intact.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(self.showPosition.bind(self), self.showError, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
```

And call it like this

```
function OnGeoClick() { 
  getGeo.getLocation();
}
```

Comment: ah ok within the args. otherwise they were binding to window in chrome. thanks. that clears alot!

Comment: but i cant do something like: var loc = getGeo.getLocation(); I want to contain it in a var